# Converting UTC timestamp to other timezone specific time

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jodatime, simpledateformat

I am working on requirement where I need to convert UTC time stamp to other zone specific timestamp.Below are the list of different timezones.

```
CET UTC+0100  
CST UTC+0800  
CST UTC-0600  
EST UTC-0500  
IST UTC+0530  
MET-1METDST   
SGT UTC+0800  
SST-8


public static String convertUTCTimeStampToOtherZoneTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp,String timeZone){
    String zoneSpecificTimeStamp="";
    try {
        DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        TimeZone zoneTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
        gmtFormat.setTimeZone(zoneTime);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String inputDateString = sdf.format(timestamp);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
         zoneSpecificTimeStamp=gmtFormat.format(sdf.parse(inputDateString));
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return zoneSpecificTimeStamp;

      }
    return zoneSpecificTimeStamp;
}
```

The above code is work fine for timezones like EST,PST,IST but for other timezones mentioned in the list the program is giving wrong results. Please update me with the correct solution for this

Comment: This has been asked SO many times.  Please search first.   Hint: you should be using time zone names like `Europe/Paris`, not `CET`.

Comment: He is actually right, same geographical location has different time zone in summer and winter.

Comment: if you are using java 8 then try using zoneddate time https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

Comment: @MattJohnson CET works.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use the full name or GMT with offset.

> ID - the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00". Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility only and full names should be used.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-

For all the time zones you have provided, there are two ways you can pass to the method.

**GMT OFFSET**

just pass the string as `"GMT {offset}"` examples:

`"GMT+0800"` instead of `"CCST UTC+0800"`

`"GMT-0600"` instead of `"CST UTC-0600"`

etc...

**ABBREVIATIONS (Not Recommended)**

Or just pass the abbreviation which you also have:

`"CST"` instead of `"CST UTC+0800"`

`"EST` instead of `"EST UTC-0500"`

**NOTE**

Although the abbreviations used in your examples seem to work, the documentation states to use full names, as the abbreviations are only for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. GMT offset is working But how to handle these two timezones. MET1METDST   
SST-8

Comment: just use SST, MET etc you need to pass the actual abbreviation otherwise pass the offset using GMT

Comment: The quote from the docs says ONLY use full names.  You then say it's ok to use abbreviations. It's not.  Only some work, and they're only there for backwards compatibility purposes.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks! :D